# How are positions visually indicated in the UCSC Genome Browser?

Tags: ucsc, genome-browser

I'm a little confused about how the position indices work in the browser. Based on the picture below, is base number 755440 an `A` or a `G`?

The general question is how do the indexing guides work? Is the base right under the `|` the one corresponding to the index or is it the one just before the `|`?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an A. The number refers to the position just before the `|`. This is clearer on different zoom levels, but I double checked by going to the [very beginning of a chromosome](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg18&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr7%3A1-33&hgsid=660570179_mIq0EMY1BriaU5C7xNPQAELZSbzv):

[image: chr7 position 1-15]

As you can see in the image above, the `|` is always after the base it refers to. I also confirmed by checking a few random positions using another genome browser which places the positions unambiguously above each base.

For more details, see [this UCSC blog post](http://genome.ucsc.edu/blog/the-ucsc-genome-browser-coordinate-counting-systems/).

Comment: Yep and the reason for this is because we store everything internally as zero based coordinates but then display everything in a 1-based format. For more information see the following blog post: http://genome.ucsc.edu/blog/the-ucsc-genome-browser-coordinate-counting-systems/

Comment: @ChristopherLee thank you! I had actually written out an answer stating that it must be the position _after_ since bed files start at 0 and then thought to check, just to make sure, and was very much surprised that it was actually the position before!